# use reference data from a sql database in stream analytics

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

In my Stream analytics ,I am getting data from Iot hub for a ID  and I want to use reference data to get data from SQL SERVER for that ID.

I use:

```
Declare @ID int=1
select 1,2,3
from [table]
where ID=@ID
```

it says no data .

even if I run

```
select 1,2,3
from [table]
```

I can't see  Sample Data on your SQL Database Reference input to test why data is not coming.

Comment: What's your complete query sql in your ASA job, would you please post it?

Comment: I got the Answer,I have a column called Amount,I was using SUM(Amount) so SA gave error that ,cannot have decimal value,so I cast-ed that to Float.<br/> Regarding my question :"I can't see Sample Data on your SQL Database Reference input to test why data is not coming."When you test query,select the option "Select time Range" and select time ,you think data is present in DB.Very imp :when you run the SA please check the "Activity Log" mentioned in the Pane as when the job fails it tells that job failed and we can click to that link and can see complete error in the JSON file.

Comment: Cheers! I tried to summarize your solution as answer,you could accept it as an answer which is may beneficial for other persons. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just summarize here:

Let's say i have a column called `Amount`, i was using `SUM(Amount)` so SA gave error : `cannot have decimal value`. So I cast-ed that to `Float`.

Regarding my question :

> "I can't see Sample Data on your SQL Database Reference input to test
>   why data is not coming."

When you test query,select the option `"Select time Range"` and select time ,you think data is present in DB. When you run the SA please check the `"Activity Log"` mentioned in the Pane as when the job fails it tells that job failed and we can click to that link and can see complete error in the JSON file.